# ESP12e pin 13 won't set to output/won't work

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, pins

I have an ESP12e and running a basic blink code on it. The problem is that GPIO13 of esp12e wont turn on. I have noticed that this has happened from time to time. Earlier I thought that the ESP was faulty so i just changed them. But now I have a lot of 10 ESPs and all of them have the same problem. Pin 13 wont turn on setting to HIGH.

What could be going wrong? Is there something that I am missing?

**EDIT:**
However, on the same piece of esp12, for some test, i tried putting the gpio12 to input and that worked.

**Code:**

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}


void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: and this is with no other hardware or libraries?

Comment: How are you determining that GPIO13 is not high?

Comment: Basic blink code uses, `LED_BUILTIN` ... on a generic module this is preset to `1` ... have you remembered to set LED to 13

Comment: @dandavis Ya, nothing else.

Comment: @JaromandaX umm, the led that I connect to it wont light up, nor does any reading show on a multimeter. And yes, the pin is set to gpio13.

Comment: `i tried putting the gpio12 to input` ... how is that relevant to gpio13 as output?

Comment: @JaromandaX, In the prodct that we are using this for, the gpio12 is working as input. I thought none of the gpios on that side were working. But the problem seems with just gpio13.

Comment: so, to summarise, you have 10 (at least) EPS12E, and not one gpio13 is working using the *ESP8266 library blink code example* - can you post *in the question* the code you are uploading to the ESP12E? I ask because it may be different with the version of arduino for esp8266 you are using compared to the one I'm using